# Why is it the case that off-policy evaluation using importance sampling suffers from high variance?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, off-policy-methods, importance-sampling

The average return for trajectories, $V^{\pi_e}$(s) is often computed via the importance sampling estimate $$V^{\pi_e}(s) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{t=0}^{H}\frac{\pi_e(a_t | s_t)}{\pi_b(a_t|s_t)}G_i$$ where $G_i$is the reward observed for the $i$th trajectory. [Sutton and Barton gives an example whereby the variance could be infinite](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf).

In general, however, why does this estimator suffer from high variance? Is it because $\pi_e(a_t|s_t)$ is mainly deterministic and, therefore, the importance weight is $0$ for most trajectories, rendering those sample trajectories useless?